# Is there a way to give a custom type name for OpenAPI

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I have a custom type to generate an OpenAPI schema for Java 11 defined class, for ex

```
MyUglyClassName {
    public MyGenericType<Long> number;
}
```

This would produce an OpenAPI with the two ref names - `MyUglyClassName` and `MyGenericTypeLong`.

I can amend this for `MyUglyClassName` using `@JsonRootName("BeautifulName")`. Is there a way to do the same for `MyGenericType<Long>`?

Thanks,